# iOS app not receiving push notifications from Twilio programmable chat

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, twilio

I have started a new project to try out Twilio programable chat but I'm not able to get the push notifications to work.

I am using Firebase to handle the push notifications and notifications directly from Firebase are working fine.

Now here's how I've configured everything:

I am using a Twilio function for my chat to work. I've created an FCM push credential on Twilio dashboard and when asked for the `FCM SECRET` I've added the `Server key` that was inside the `Cloud Messaging Settings` on Firebase console.

I have updated the push notification configuration to enable notifications on a new message on the dashboard like this:

[image: Twilio notifications dashboard screenshot]

On the app I do have push notifications working, because I am able to receive notifications directly from Firebase.

I've registered for remote notifications on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like this:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { _, _ in }
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

On AppDelegate I'm actually receiving the device token, storing it for later and setting it on my chat client

```swift
static var token: Data?

func application(_: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        AppDelegate.token = deviceToken
}
```

After that, when I'm creating my chat client, I set the device token and the callback's result is successful

```swift
func signIn(identity: String) {
        self.identity = identity
        tokenService.retrieveToken(identity: identity) { result in
            if case let .success(token) = result {
                TwilioChatClient.chatClient(withToken: token, properties: nil, delegate: self) { _, client in
                    self.client = client
                    if let pushToken = AppDelegate.token {
                        client?.register(withNotificationToken: pushToken) { result in
                            print(result.isSuccessful()) // this prints true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After all this setup I'm still not able to receive push notifications, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue. My problem was that I was not able to receive push notifications on iOS 13.

For me the solution was to **update the Twilio SDK** within iOS Project.

Right now it is v.4.0.0

Comment: I don't think that's it since I'm already using v4.0.0. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Can you think of anything else you did differently from what I've described?

Comment: The part where you register deviceToken with Twilio client is identical to what I am doing...
I must say Twilio push-notifications for some reason doesn't work for me well today. It works for some time, then, in an hour, it stops working without me doing/changing anything...